# How to fetch Foreign Key Value in REST Api using TastyPie?

Tags: python, mysql, django, tastypie

Hi I am using `Tastypie` with my `Django` project. When i fetch the model value which have foreign key relation ship with other model in resource `api`, its returning empty value.

I am using MySql as my database.

My Model Code:

`TopicDetail` Model

```
class Topicdetails(models.Model):
    apptopicid = models.IntegerField(db_column='appTopicID', primary_key=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    portaltopicid = models.IntegerField(db_column='portalTopicID', blank=True, null=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    topicname = models.CharField(db_column='topicName', max_length=500, blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    topicshortdescription = models.CharField(db_column='topicShortDescription', max_length=5000, blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'TopicDetails'
```

`Instructor Detail` Model

```
class Instructordetails(models.Model): 
    appinstructorid = models.IntegerField(db_column='appInstructorID', primary_key=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    portalinstructorid = models.IntegerField(db_column='portalInstructorID') # Field name made lowercase.
    firstname = models.CharField(db_column='firstName', max_length=50, blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    middlename = models.CharField(db_column='middleName', max_length=50, blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    lastname = models.CharField(db_column='lastName', max_length=50, blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    optionalid = models.IntegerField(db_column='optionalID', blank=True, null=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'InstructorDetails'
```

`TopicInstructor` Model , Which have two foreign key from above two models.

```
class Topicinstructor(models.Model):
    topicinstructorrelationid = models.IntegerField(db_column='topicInstructorRelationID', primary_key=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    apptopicid = models.ForeignKey(Topicdetails, db_column='appTopicID') # Field name made lowercase.
    appinstructorid = models.ForeignKey(Instructordetails, db_column='appInstructorID') # Field name made lowercase.
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'TopicInstructor'
```

And my TopicInstructor api code:

```
class TopicinstructorResource(ModelResource):
    # topicdetails = fields.ForeignKey(TopicdetailsResource,'topicdetails')
    #instructordetails = fields.ForeignKey(InstructordetailsResource, 'instructordetails')
    class Meta:
        queryset = Topicinstructor.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'topicinstructor'
        include_resource_uri = False
```

If I un comment above two lines of code from my resource api its show error:

```
{
error: "The model '&lt;Topicinstructor: Topicinstructor object&gt;' has an empty attribute 'instructordetails' and doesn't allow a null value."
}
```

When if fetch the resource its returning the output as below:

```
{
meta: {
    limit: 20,
    next: "/api/topicinstructor/?offset=20&limit=20&format=json",
    offset: 0,
    previous: null,
    total_count: 994
    },
objects: [
    {
        topicinstructorrelationid: 1
    },
    {
        topicinstructorrelationid: 2
    },
    {
        topicinstructorrelationid: 3
    },
    {
        topicinstructorrelationid: 4
    },
  ]
}
```

But i need to fetch the foreign key value also. More on that i created my model file from MySql Database using `python manage.py inspectdb` command.

Kindly help me.....

Answer (score 0):

put `null=True` such that it allows null values

```
topicdetails = fields.ForeignKey(TopicdetailsResource,'topicdetails',null=True)
 instructordetails = fields.ForeignKey(InstructordetailsResource,'instructordetails',null=True)
```

Comment: if i add modify my code according to your suggestion, it returning all objects as null. but i have value in my data base. For sample output after modification                                     objects: [
    {
    instructordetails: null,
    topicdetails: null,
    topicinstructorrelationid: 1
    },                                                                                      ]

Comment: i am not getting `if my foreign key reference are null` means

Comment: i mentioned my question 'TopicInstructor` wont contain any null field.

Comment: @Nagarajan i think you place null=True only for instructordetails  and try

Comment: i need to fetch only two `apptopicid` form `topicdetails` model and `appinstructorid` from `instructordetail` model. what changes i have to do in my code for this output